# How to configure Jenkins remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, remote-server, jenkins-cli

I have to configure Jenkins installed in Ubuntu server from my Mac machine through ssh. The jenkins is installed in the server with following commands as stated in

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu 
here.

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo  apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ >   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

And also jenkins was started using

```
service jenkins restart
```

Is there any way to configure Jenkins and work with from my mac?.

What kind of user privileges(for ubuntu server) I may need?

Do I need to Install jenkins CLI to configure remotely?

Please ask for clarification if anything needed to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is your mac on the same network as your ubuntu server? If yes, you can type the url directly of your jenkins in your mac and login to the jenkins server.

if Jenkins is running on port 8080 and the ip of the ubuntu server is 10.10.0.3 you can access jenkins by typing http://10.10.0.3:8080 - you should be on the same network though.

Comment: Yes Thanks. I solved by myself using the same method as you described. Up voted.

Comment: The "you should be on the same network though" caught me out. Thanks for detailing this in your answer! I think a lot of jenkins tutorials and documentations carelessly omit this.